# What is the difference between the 'basis' and 'DiscountBasis' in 'bndtotalreturn'----matlab function

Tags: matlab, finance, quantitative-finance, quantitative

bndtotalreturn is function in matlab Financial Toolbox .  Two Input Arguments for bndtotalreturn is about leap year . One is 'basis',another 'DiscountBasis' .What is the difference between the 'basis' and 'DiscountBasis'? it's confusing

I make a leap year test .

1、 basis=0   DiscountBasis=3     get the correct result

2、basis=3   DiscountBasis=0     get wrong result

It seems that 'DiscountBasis' doesn't matter because it doesn't work！ But the basis played a decisive role！

Is it right？

[bndtotalreturn](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/finance/bndtotalreturn.html)

```
Price = 106.9302;
CouponRate = 0.08;
Settle = '15-Jan-2020';
Maturity = '1-Jan-2023';
ReinvestRate = 0.06;
Face = 100;
Basis = 3;  %计算方式 actual/365
IssueDate = '1-Jan-2020';
Period = 1;
HorizonPrice = 106.9302;
HorizonDate = '1-Mar-2020';
CompoundingFrequency = 1;  %复利频率 1代表年度复利
DiscountBasis = 0;          %折现因子计算方式 actual/365
[BondEquiv,EffectiveRate] = bndtotalreturn(Price,CouponRate,Settle,Maturity,ReinvestRate,...
    'Face',Face,'IssueDate',IssueDate,'Period',Period,'HorizonPrice',HorizonPrice,'HorizonDate',...
    HorizonDate,'CompoundingFrequency',CompoundingFrequency,'DiscountBasis',DiscountBasis,'Basis',Basis)
```

function in Financial Toolbox .  Two Input Arguments